# Why doesn't electricity and magnetism distort space as well?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, spacetime

I think Kaluza/Klein was partly worked on to find additional dimensions to account for electric and magnetic fields.

I am confused why the gravity field gets the privileged spot of distorting space-time, whereas electric and magnetic fields have to use some other mechanism.

Is this somehow related to electric and magnetic fields having attractive and repelling force modes?

Comment: See also [Can all fundamental forces be fictitious forces?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148028/can-all-fundamental-forces-be-fictitious-forces)

Comment: I don't find the answers to the cited question (placed in the post) responsive.