# In layman's terms why is the time component of the stress-energy tensor associated with energy density?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, time, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Why is the time component of the stress energy tensor $T^{00}$ associated as energy density?

Answer (score 5):

Consider a stationary box of volume $V$ filled with total electric charge $Q$.  The charge density of the box is $\rho_0 = \frac{Q}{V}$, and the box is stationary so the current density is zero.  If you boost to a frame moving with relative velocity $-\mathbf v$, then the volume of the box will be contracted, and so the charge density will increase; the new charge density will be $\rho = \gamma \rho_0$, where $\gamma \equiv (1-v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$.  At the same time, the observed current density would become $\rho \mathbf v = \gamma \rho_0 \mathbf v$.

The charge density and current density transform like the time and space components of a 4-vector, so we introduce
$$\mathbf J = (c\rho,\rho \mathbf v)$$

---

Now consider a stationary box of volume $V$ filled with mass $m$.  The energy density of the box is $u_0=\frac{mc^2}{V}$, and the box is stationary, so the momentum density of the box is zero. If you boost to a frame moving with relative velocity $-\mathbf v$, then the volume of the box will be contracted, **and the energy of the box will increase**, so the energy density will increase *twice*; the new energy density will be
$$u = \frac{\gamma mc^2}{V/\gamma}=\gamma^2 u_0$$
and the new momentum density will be $\frac{1}{c^2}\gamma^2 u_0 \mathbf v$.

Energy density and momentum density (unlike charge density and current density) do not transform like the components of a 4-vector.  They do, however, transform as though we defined a (2,0)-tensor with components

$$T^{\mu \nu} = \pmatrix{u_0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}$$
and performed a Lorentz transformation on it.  Let $\mathbf v = v\hat x$, so

$$\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu} = \pmatrix{\gamma & \beta\gamma & 0 & 0 \\ \beta\gamma&\gamma&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}$$

We then have

$$\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \rho}\Lambda^\nu_{\ \ \sigma}T^{\rho\sigma}=\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ 0}\Lambda^\nu_{\ \ 0}u_0 = \pmatrix{\gamma^2 u_0& \frac{1}{c}\gamma^2 u_0v&0&0\\ \frac{1}{c}\gamma^2u_0 v& \frac{1}{c^2}\gamma^2 u_0v^2& 0 & 0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}=T'^{\mu \nu}$$

$T^{00}$ is identified with energy density, while $T^{0i}=T^{i0}$ are identified with momentum density (times $c$).  The physical interpretation of the $T^{ij}$ term is not so obvious; its interpretation is borne out when one performs the same analysis on a relativistic fluid, in which case the $T^{ij}$ terms are identified with the fluid's stress tensor.

---

> What why is energy density in the time component of the tensor? Or to put it another way what does energy density have to do with time?

Energy has a very deep connection with time.  In this case, it is the $00$-component of the stress-energy tensor ultimately  because it is the $0$-component of the 4-momentum.

The deeper explanation for this is that energy is the [conserved Noether charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) associated with time-translation symmetry.  If a theory with Lagrangian $L$ is invariant under spacetime translations $x^\mu \rightarrow x^\mu + dx^\mu$, then a quantity $p^\mu$ (the 4-momentum) is conserved; $x^0$ is time and $p^0$ is energy.  The continued association between energy and time extends to the stress-energy tensor.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth reply. However I'm still a little confused. What why is energy density in the time component of the tensor? Or to put it another way what does energy density have to do with time?

Comment: @Aneikei I have added a small additional explanation to the end of my answer.

Comment: Energy has a deep connection with time or would that be duration?

Comment: @Aneikei Time, and shifts therein.

Comment: Hi. So I've been giving this some pondering and I think I understand. When you say that energy has a deep connection with time are you referring to E=hv. Which is energy density. The more energy received per unit of time the greater the energy density. Which is also how kinetic energy operates right?