# Electromagnetism as curvature of space-time?

Tags: electromagnetism, geodesics, free-fall

If gravity can be expressed as a curvature of spacetime, can electromagnetism similarly be expressed as curvature on higher dimensions of spacetime?

Also (I'm not sure if the 2 questions are linked), does an "electromagnetic free fall" exist? In other words, is there a mathematical way to calculate electromagnetic geodesics?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can all fundamental forces be fictitious forces?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148028/)

Comment: I voted to reopen because the duplicate question, while asking basically the same, is on a much higher level, and thus also its answers. I'd like to give an answer which elaborates the equivalence principle on school level.

Comment: See [Kaluza-Klein theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory)

Comment: Note that curvature in GR does not need higher dimensions – it's "intrinsic" curvature i.e. only happens in the four dimensions of spacetime.