# If light is affected by gravity, does that mean gravity affects electrical&magnetic fields too?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, visible-light, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Since we observed that masses indeed bend the light, and since we consider light to be composed of electrical and magnetic fields, does that mean a single point charge will result with bent electrical fields near a large mass? (same goes for magnetic field of course)

Comment: Very related question with good answers here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30477/if-gravity-is-a-bend-in-space-time-then-what-is-magnetism

Comment: Yes. It really does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, visible light is part of the electromagnetic spectrum, and gravity affects both.